# Can all loops and if statements be replaced by map, filter, and reduce?

Tags: functional-programming

Someone told me you could do this most of the time, and I was wondering if there was some sort of proof that you could do it in general.  (Assuming we're using a language like Python that has map, filter, and reduce functions.)

Comment: What functions can be passed? I can cheat your problem statement by mapping over a dummy one element list and pass arbitrary code with ifs and loops.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you can pass along any function to `map`, `filter` and `reduce`, yes. You can do everything with it (although some might require some hacks).

For example, one slightly harder example to emulate because you need to save state (can be done with reduce, but not in 1 statement):

```
min_ = max_ = sum_ = items[0]
i = 0.
for item in items:
    i += 1
    min_ = min(item, min_)
    max_ = max(item, max_)
    sum_ += item
avg = sum_ / i
```

The functional variant:

```
min_ = reduce(lambda x, y: min(x, y), items, items[0])
max_ = reduce(lambda x, y: max(x, y), items, items[0])
sum_ = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, items, items[0])
avg = sum_ / len(items)
```

Actually... just thought of a way to do it in 1 reduce statement:

```
min_, max_, sum_ = reduce(lambda x, y: (min(x[0], y), max(x[1], y), x[2] + y), items, [items[0]] * 3)
avg = float(sum_) / len(items)
```